# MediaLayout example with Slider. Slider not moves in iOS, like the binding for Buffering is not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, toolkit

I am using the Microsoft example of MediaElement with Slider as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement#implement-a-custom-position-bar). **In Android it works** and the Slider runs while Buffering, but **in iOS it doesn't work**. Remain Stopped at the Beggining.
I am using a CaroulselView with MediaElement and don't know if can be a bug related. But again, it just happens with iOS.

I am posting here because I opened an Issue on [Git](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1936)
, but no one answered.

My XAML:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="carouselStorys"
                      ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding StorysList}"
                      PositionChanged="carouselView_PositionChanged" >
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="150,*" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*, Auto">

                        <xct:MediaElement   Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Aspect="AspectFill"
                                            x:Name="mediaElement" AutoPlay="True"
                                            MediaEnded="mediaElement_MediaEnded"
                                            BindingContextChanged="MediaElement_BindingContextChanged"
                                            Source="{Binding Story.Source}"
                                            ShowsPlaybackControls="False"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        
                        
                        <customcontrols:CustomSlider    Margin="0,20" 
                                                        Grid.Row="0" 
                                                        Grid.Column="1" 
                                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                                   
                                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                        BindingContext="{x:Reference mediaElement}" 
                                                        Maximum="{Binding Duration, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}}"
                                                        Value="{Binding Position, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}}" 
                                                        >
                            <!--<customcontrols:CustomSlider.IsVisible>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" iOS="False" Android="True"/>
                            </customcontrols:CustomSlider.IsVisible>-->
                            <customcontrols:CustomSlider.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="customcontrols:CustomSlider"
                                             Binding="{Binding CurrentState}"
                                             Value="{x:Static xct:MediaElementState.Buffering}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </customcontrols:CustomSlider.Triggers>
                        </customcontrols:CustomSlider>
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage         Grid.Row="0"
                                                            Margin="20"
                                                            WidthRequest="40"
                                                            HeightRequest="40"
                                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                            CacheDuration="50"
                                                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                            DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                                                            BitmapOptimizations="True"
                                                            Source= "{Binding Story.UserImage}">
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                <fftransformations:CircleTransformation       />
                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                        
                        <Label Margin="20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="X" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

My .cs code

```
public partial class StoriesPage : ContentPage
    {
        DashboardViewModel _viewModel;
        public ObservableCollection<User> templist { get; set; }
        List<MediaElement> mediaElements = new List<MediaElement>();

        public StoriesPage (DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = _viewModel = dashboardViewModel;
            _viewModel.CurrentPosition = _viewModel.StorysList.IndexOf(_viewModel.SelectedItem);
            carouselStorys.Position = _viewModel.CurrentPosition;
            templist = new ObservableCollection<User> (_viewModel.StorysList);
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            AddToTempList();
            
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        private void mediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (carouselStorys.Position == _viewModel.CountStorysList -1)
                App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            else
                carouselStorys.ScrollTo(_viewModel.CurrentPosition + 1);
        }

        private void MediaElement_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as MediaElement;
            mediaElements.Add(element);
        }

        private void carouselView_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (carouselStorys.CurrentItem == null)
                return;

            //AutoPlay when using CaroulselView not works after third scroll in Android. Video doesn't play and stay a black view like it's not buffering.
            //With this code I force playing and it's buffering.
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                mediaElements[mediaElements.Count - 2].Stop();
                mediaElements.Last().Play();
            }


            _viewModel.CurrentPosition = carouselStorys.Position;
            AddToTempList();
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carouselStorys.ItemsSource = null;
            StorysSingleton.Storys = templist;
            //PopAsync removed, because there is a Bug in SfTabView, that sometimes when Popped, the tabbar disappear.
            //todo check later if it doesn´t happen.
            //Navigation.PopAsync();
            App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyTabbedPage());
        }

        async Task AddToTempList()
        {
            var currentUser = carouselStorys.CurrentItem as User;
            foreach (var user in templist)
            {
                if (user.Id == currentUser.Id)
                {
                    templist.Remove(user);
                    user.Story.IsNew = false;
                    templist.Add(user);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to post the actual code that illustrates the problem

Comment: @Jason Sorry...I am posting right now... Please remove the Close vote.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, since you have created an issue , we need to be patient and wait for the update and new version to be released.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT But the problem is that no one answered and I don´t think will be released a new version as you are just fixing for MAUI. Am I wrong ? What I need is someone that give me some "quick fix"... maybe someone is having the same problem